# "ORA-1017: invalid username/password; logon denied" while trying to log in using sys

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g

```
try
{
  OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
  con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=TNSName;User Id=sys;Password=password;DBA Privilege=sysdba;";
  con.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex )
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I am trying to create a connection as sysdba but getting the exception:

**"ORA-1017: invalid username/password; logon denied"**

whereas i am able to log in into the same user using SQLDBX from the same machine.I am also able to create a connection using the same code omitting **"DBA Privilege=sysdba"** and using a normal user.

Comment: Can you try through `SQL*Plus`, execute the following in the `command prompt` :- `sqlplus / as sysdba` You should have Oracle client installed and assuming it is your local database to test this.

Comment: I have a different database server but yes i have Oracle client installed and TNS Name correctly configured.

Comment: I don't think your issue is with the password I think its with the sysdba role tag. Can you execute this query: `select * from v$pwfile_users` and give the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are tring to connect to 11g database with lower version of oracle driver (ie. 10g ODP.NET or lower version)  you receive the above error.

because whenever we send the passwords using 10g ODP.NET ,it converts them into all upper cases. The passwords are case-insensitive. 
 click
[here](http://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/ora-01017-invalid-usernamepassword-logon-denied/)  or [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/2198228) to see the details.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Oracle 11g [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT184), I think the DB privilege is case sensitive. So try with:

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=TNSName;User Id=sys;Password=password;DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;";
```

assuming that the specified user id and password are correct.